# Openstack, Nova and --help: "Could not load EntryPoint.parse" error

Tags: python, openstack, openstack-nova

## The setup

I have installed devstack on my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, 64-bit, using the newest build from the official repo.

## The problem

Whenever I run `openstack --help` in the terminal, usage, description and optional arguments all display normally, but all except 2~4 commands display like this:

```
Could not load EntryPoint.parse('server_show = openstackclient.compute.v2.server:ShowServer')
Could not load EntryPoint.parse('server_ssh = openstackclient.compute.v2.server:SshServer')
Could not load EntryPoint.parse('server_suspend = openstackclient.compute.v2.server:SuspendServer')
```

Running `openstack --debug --help` shows that the root of these problems **seems** to be version conflict of python (all of the commands share the last two lines):

```
Could not load EntryPoint.parse('backup_list = openstackclient.volume.v1.backup:ListBackup')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cliff/help.py", line 22, in __call__
factory = ep.load()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2369, in load
    self.require(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2386, in require
    items = working_set.resolve(reqs, env, installer)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 851, in resolve
    raise VersionConflict(dist, req).with_context(dependent_req)
VersionConflict: (python-neutronclient 3.0.0 (/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages), Requirement.parse('python-neutronclient<3,>=2.6.0'))
Could not load EntryPoint.parse('backup_restore = openstackclient.volume.v1.backup:RestoreBackup')
```

## Attempts at solving

I double checked, and I have both python 2.7.6 and 3.4.3 installed. As per [this answer to an unrelated question](https://askubuntu.com/a/449558/444952), I set up `alias python=python2`, but this didn't seem to change anything. Setting back `alias python=python3` didn't help either. (Alias is working, since `python --version` displays the correct version number.)

I've found another person [with the exact same problem](https://bugs.launchpad.net/horizon/+bug/1497985), but nobody commented on their post.

I suspect this error might be a symptom of a configuration/installation problem that causes other basic commands to display anomalous behaviour. Is there any way I can fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/openstack/requirements/commit/840d85eb5301cc63225f1fd7fbdb4f9ca2cc8489 has update python-neutronclient to ===3.1.0, which happens at sep 23, which means both master and stable/liberty have such change, stable/kilo has pined it to 2.6.0. I don't know what version are you using, and what newest are you mean.

Comment: I installed by running `stack.sh` after downloading it by `git clone https://git.openstack.org/openstack-dev/devstack` on 11th November. Is that an old link?

Comment: and with neutron service enabled?

Comment: Neutron responds to `neutron --version` with 3.0.0 so I suppose it is enabled. Can I update just neutron?